# A TLS fatal alert has been received with apt

Tags: networking, apt, updates, proxy

When I run `sudo apt update` this return "A TLS fatal alert has been received" to the repositories on `https`.

```
Err:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal Release                                                       
  Could not handshake: A TLS fatal alert has been received. [IP: 10.0.3.10 80]
```

It seem to be a problem with gnutls tools, throug the proxy.

When I run gnutls-cli directly to this host the response is the same.

```
gnutls-cli download.docker.com
Processed 128 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'download.docker.com:443'...
Connecting to '13.227.92.69:443'...
*** Fatal error: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
*** Received alert [49]: Access was denied
```

The proxy is configured in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and the repositories on `http` are working fine, and on the browser can access to this url.

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://10.0.3.10:80";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://10.0.3.10:80";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://10.0.3.10:80";
```

what is missing?

Comment: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal Release  This site is having issues.

Comment: Your proxy is denying access to the docker site for downloads.  And/or the site is having issues, though the site works fine from here.